# Why am I getting terrible download speeds?

Tags: networking, internet, router, home-networking

I just bought a new router, and for some reason, when I'm using it I get terrible download speeds (< .01 Mbps).  My upload speed seems fine (2 Mbps).  Anyone have any idea what is going on?

The model is a Netgear N300 (WNR2000v3).  I can share any router settings if need be.

Comment: What connection type is it?  If it is ADSL look for sync speeds in the N300 status page.  In fact, if you take a screen shot of the status page and [edit] and add to your question it will help.

Comment: How are you measuring the speeds? And did you change anything else other than the router? Have you tested wired?

Comment: If you try to copy a file from another PC in your own network, do you still get low speed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used Speedtest.net.  I should also mention that Both wireless and wired connection are experiencing slow speeds.

Comment: @Paul I'm not using ADSL, just a standard cable connection

Comment: @Robert Ill try that when I get home and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The telephone wire's lenght may be one factor. Try putting your dsl modem near your phone, with a short wire. I had the same problem and solved it by moving the router and the modem to the nearest place to the adsl filter I could.

Your ISP could be the other factor (in my country there's only one, and it sucks)